# Sign JWT with .p8 file from Apple with Node.JS

Tags: node.js, jwt, app-store-connect

I found this ruby script doing exactly what I need. To sign JWT with .p8

https://shashikantjagtap.net/wwdc18-a-basic-guide-to-app-store-connect-api/

But how do I do this part in Node.JS?

private_key = OpenSSL::PKey.read(File.read(path_to_your_private_key/AuthKey_#{KEY_ID}.p8))

Comment: https://github.com/Tobi042/apple-music-api-jwt-creator/blob/30057e0c760aee0bd8579573e3f5882b251a9324/pages/index.tsx#L73-L79

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to use anything fancy.

`const privateKey = fs.readFileSync("./AuthKey_123456789Z.p8")`

Will read the file just fine and then you can use it with a JWT creation thingy like [jsonwebtoken](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken),
.p8 is just a text file.
You can also add `utf8` to read the file, like so:

`fs.readFileSync("./AuthKey_123456789Z.p8", 'utf8')`

Then if you console.log() `privateKey` you should see your .p8 file, something like this:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
0GIBBERISHGIBBERISHGIBBERISHGIBBERISHGIBBERISHGIBBERISHQgS/GIBBERISHf+lol
GIBBERISHukEMK5JaG123123456456YBLABLABLABLABLABLAATH8mUGIBBERISH
GIBBERISHUPVOTETHISYESALIENFUCKERISAGREATBANDUPVOTETHISGIBBERISH
12345678Z
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

But as far as jsonwebtoken (the npm package) is concerned, it doesn't even matter whether you use the 'utf8' parameter or not.

Comment: I get `Key must be one of type KeyObject or CryptoKey` when I send the string read from the P8 file to the jwt signing function.